# How to suppress a subreport in crystal reports version 10.0?

Tags: crystal-reports, c#-2.0

I need to suppress a subreport.  I have a parameter field named "TransactionType"; only if TransactionType is "Multiple" do I need to show the subreport option; otherwise, it should show blank.  I have checked suppress option in subreport.  I need a formula for suppressing a subreport if transactiontype is Multiple then show subreport or else do not. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put the subreport into a footer section all by itself.  In the section properties (get there via the Section Expert) set the suppress option's formula to
(TransactionType <> "Multiple") Then True;